# Difference in partial dependence calculated by R and Python

Tags: r, regression, scikit-learn, boosting

I noticed there's a difference in partial dependence calculated by R package `gbm` and Python's `scikit-learn`.

Here's `gbm`'s partial dependence of median value on median income of the California housing dataset:

[image]

And here's `scikit-learn`':
[image]

It's easy to see that R's partial dependence ranges from 1.5 to 4.5, whereas `scikit-learn`'s from -0.5 to 1.5, but the shape of the lines is nearly the same. I don't get why it's like that.

Relevant code:

R

```
library(oem)
library(gbm)
data(calHousing)
X <- calHousing[ ,!(colnames(calHousing) == "medianValue")]
y <- calHousing$medianValue / 100000
gbm.model <- gbm.fit(X, y, distribution="gaussian", n.trees=100, interaction.depth=12, shrinkage=0.15)
plot(gbm.model, i.var="medianIncome")
```

Python code is a copy-paste from `scikit-learn`' [example page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_partial_dependence.html).

```
print(__doc__)

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble.partial_dependence import plot_partial_dependence
from sklearn.ensemble.partial_dependence import partial_dependence
from sklearn.datasets.california_housing import fetch_california_housing


def main():
    cal_housing = fetch_california_housing()
    # import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    # split 80/20 train-test
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(cal_housing.data,
                                                        cal_housing.target,
                                                        test_size=0.2,
                                                        random_state=1)
    names = cal_housing.feature_names

    print('_' * 80)
    print("Training GBRT...")
    clf = GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=100, max_depth=12, min_samples_split=10,
                                    learning_rate=0.15, loss='ls', subsample=0.5,
                                    random_state=1)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print("done.")

    print('_' * 80)
    print('Convenience plot with ``partial_dependence_plots``')
    print

    features = [0, 5, 1, 2, (5, 1)]
    fig, axs = plot_partial_dependence(clf, X_train, features,
                                       feature_names=names,
                                       n_jobs=3, grid_resolution=100)
    fig.suptitle('Partial dependence of house value on nonlocation features\n'
                 'for the California housing dataset')
    plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)  # tight_layout causes overlap with suptitle
    plt.show()


# Needed on Windows because plot_partial_dependence uses multiprocessing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: My guess is some sort of standardization took place for the outcome variable for scikit-learn (either in the underlying data or for the plotting function) that didn't take place in the R example.

Comment: Max depth and interaction depth do not mean the same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scikit-learn center the partial dependence with **the mean of the target value**, R does not.

Here is an example using diabetes dataset.

### R

```
data(diabetes, package="lars")

y        <- diabetes$y
x        <- diabetes$x
class(x) <- "matrix"
data     <- data.frame(y, as.data.frame(x))

model <- gbm::gbm(formula = y ~ . , data = data, distribution = "gaussian", 
                  shrinkage = 1, bag.fraction = 1, n.trees = 100,
                  interaction.depth = 2, verbose = T, keep.data = F)

partial <- plot.gbm(dgbm, i.var = 1, return.grid = T)
plot(partial[, 2] - mean(y), type = "l")
```

[image: R partial plot]

### Python

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn.datasets
import sklearn.ensemble
from sklearn.ensemble.partial_dependence import partial_dependence

diabetes = sklearn.datasets.load_diabetes()
X= diabetes.data
y= diabetes.target



gbm = sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(loss='ls', learning_rate=1, max_leaf_nodes=3, min_samples_leaf=10,
                                             n_estimators=100, verbose=True)
model_gbm = gbm.fit(X, y)

partial, axe = partial_dependence(gbrt=model_gbm, X=X, target_variables=(0))

plt.plot(partial.T)
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer, I wish I could upvote it twice.  Any idea why Scikit-learn would subtract off the mean of the target variable? Isn't is nice to see, for a given independent variable, what the predicted target variable is after averaging over your data?

Comment: @EtienneKintzler, how would the scale on y-axis get affected in case of classification.